# How do I change the WooCommerce Notice Banner CSS? (Other solutions not working - code provided)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The code I have tried in style.css is:

```
.woocommerce-store-notice, p.demo_store {
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I have consolidated with other sources to confirm this was correct without resolution. It simply does not change the notice. It may be worth noting that I am editing the multi-currency banner for WooCommerce, but the provided classes match with what is found on Google Chrome's inspect.